# ERROR: ERROR: Could not find a version that matches djangomysqlrestframework

Tags: django, pip

I am trying to install djangomysqlrest framework in my django project which is created inside pipenv.
i tried the following command:

```
  pipenv install djangorestframework
   pipenv install djangomysqlrestframework
```

but in both cases it is giving following error:
x Locking Failed!
....
....

```
ERROR: ERROR: Could not find a version that matches djangomysqlrestframework
```

Comment: Check if you can visit https://pypi.org from your browser. This error occurs due to one of many reasons like SSL/TLS error, or your ISP blocking you from accessing pypi servers or pypi servers may have blacklisted your IP.

Answer (score 0):

There is no [djangomysqlrestframework](https://pypi.org/project/djangomysqlrestframework/) package at PyPI, hence the error. What are you trying to install? Should it be just `djangorestframework` and `django-mysql`?